# AWS Config Credentials are not being accessed in docker

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-secrets-manager

I setup secret manager on my local system and now I have .aws directory in my windows root directory. And by using the following code, I am retrieving my access-key-id and value.

```
client.getSecretValue({SecretId: secretName}, function(err, data) {
// console.log(err);
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    if (err.code === 'DecryptionFailureException')
        // Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
        throw err;
    else if (err.code === 'InternalServiceErrorException')
        // An error occurred on the server side.
        throw err;
    else if (err.code === 'InvalidParameterException')
        // You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
        throw err;
    else if (err.code === 'InvalidRequestException')
        // You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
        throw err;
    else if (err.code === 'ResourceNotFoundException')
        // We can't find the resource that you asked for.
        throw err;
}
else {
    
    // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
    // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
    if ('SecretString' in data) {
        secret = JSON.parse(data.SecretString);
        secretKey = secret["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"];
        clientID = secret["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"];
        secret.region = "us-east-1";
        global.secret = secret;
    } else {
        let buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
        decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString('ascii');
    }

    // routes 
   
    require('./services')(router,validation);
}
```

});

It is working well. But when I run the above code with docker, it gets failed with following error

> **Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1.**

Comment: This will be failing because the secrets manager client is returning this error, are you specifying any credentials to this client?

Comment: thanks for your quick response @Chris Williams. Actually, I have file named as .credentials in .aws directory and it has the access key id and secret. It works when I don't use docker but with docker it throws issue

Comment: Has it been created in the Docker container?

Comment: No, its not created there. Can you please suggest me how can i achieve that ? I did some r&d and found this one 
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 -v ~/.aws/:/root/.aws/ --user=root service-docker-image-2:latest . But it didn't work.

Comment: When you say didn't work, did it return an error running that command or did it just have no effect?

Comment: the command didn't return any error but after the if condition in my code, I have console.log (as you can see in 3rd line). it throws the same error as mentioned in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217558/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-moazzam).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass these values in as [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) via the CLI.

To do this run using the below syntax

```
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY service-docker-image-2:latest .
```

Comment: I tried this but thows error "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 8: exec: .: Permission denied"

Comment: Ensure that this matches what you run normally but with the environment arguments added in. This was an example command to showcase :)